# swiftyJSON parsing json from NSURL

Tags: json, swift, swift2, swifty-json

i would ask a little help..

I have a function which try to get json data from a url. I am using SwiftyJSON.

this is my function:

```
  func getDataFromUpc(Code: String) {
        print("called getdata")
        let urlString = "http://api.upcdatabase.org/json/mykey/" + Code
         print(urlString)
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

        let json = JSON(data!)

        print(json)
        print(json["description"])
        self.alert(json["description"].stringValue)


    }
```

when i try to print the json object on the console i can see this: 
unknown

and when i try to print json["description"] it's nil.

If i try to call my url with my browser it's works and i get back the json response.

Could anybody please help me what am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is `data` nil? If not, what does a string like `let dataString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)` look like?

Comment: it's not nill so if i do this: let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print(dataString) i can see the full json response.. but how can i reference for json["description"] for example..? :)

Comment: thank you.. i read the spec of swifty json and with this: if let dataFromString = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {
    let json = JSON(data: dataFromString)
} its working.. :) Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps the first thing to do when using Swifty JSON (or any 3rd party code) is "read the spec".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

swiftyJSON don´t works with URL´s , swiftJSON works perfectly with local data

this is a tutorial that you can see to understand more the swiftJSON

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_NfijT6mt6A

to parse the JSON from the web you need to do that...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-LZs0De7_U